# A question of interpretation: single word parenthesis

Tags: semantics, meaning

To my mind this:

> Entity foo varies seemingly at random.

is semantically equivalent to this:

> Entity foo varies, seemingly, at random.

However, is this necessarily the case? What alternative, dissimilar interpretations might exist for each sentence?

Comment: I'm actually trying to find a place to move a comma (after "foo") and place a semicolon somewhere! :)

Comment: @pagemen: A dash can work: "Entity foo varies -- seemingly at random."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree that these sentences are equivalent. To me, the first sentence is parsed like this:

> Entity foo varies, seemingly at random.

ie `seemingly` refers to the randomness, not the variation. In the second, to my mind, `seemingly` refers to the variation.

Comment: An interesting distinction. Why do you parse the sentences as you do? Could it be equally valid to make your assertion in reverse, as it were: the second `seeingly` refers to the randomness and the first to the variation?

Comment: @trout: In this case the parenthetical signals that it deals with what just came before. The same thing happens in "I ate two meals, one of which was pizza, before I went to bed."

Answer (score 5):

In my mind, these two are more equivalent:

> Entity foo seemingly varies at random
>
> Entity foo varies, seemingly, at random

"Seemingly" can modify "varies" or "random". The distinction is less significant in this example but in other contexts it could matter more:

> I am angry at random
>
> I am seemingly angry at random
>
> I am angry, seemingly, at random
>
> I am angry seemingly at random

The relevant distinction is do I seem angry or am I angry at seemingly random times? The middle example appears the most ambiguous. For completeness, here are other ways of wording the sentences:

> I seem angry at random
>
> It seems I am angry at random
>
> I am angry at random, it seems

The distinction between "angry" in these sentences also applies to "varies" in the original examples.

Comment: I agree that in other contexts the distinction is much more significant; I thank you for your contribution but I am interested in the more subtle distinctions of the example sentences above.

Comment: @trout: That is what I was trying to convey. I added a bit at the end; hope that helps. :P